# How to validate Input from not saving 0 or less then 0 on button click?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular6

I want to save Length through input type number in angular 6. but the length shouldn't be 0 or less then 0 . It should show error on button click when someone enters 0 or less then value in input. I tried to add min="1" but it doesn't work

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                <input matInput type="number" [(ngModel)]="ItemModel.Length" placeholder="Length"  min="1"

                id="Length" name="Length" required>
              </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: It should work. If not, please provide a [mcve] of your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your min value to 0.1 and add ngclass for red border

```
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
          <input matInput [(ngModel)]="ItemModel.Length" type="number" name="Length"
            placeholder="Length" [ngClass]="{ 'red': ItemModel.Length <= 0 && 
            greaterthenzero  }" min="0.1" required>
    </mat-form-field>
```

on submit button you can check your model value and add one boolean property and set to true if value is less than 0

```
    submit() {
         this.greaterthenzero = false;
         if (this.ItemModel.Length <= 0) {
             this.greaterthenzero = true;
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

You may check this on button click event

```
if (this.form.value.controlName <= 0) {
    alert("Please enter value greater then 0");        
    return false;
  }
```

**Option 2:**

```
controlName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(0)]]
```

In HTML

```
<span *ngIf="f.controlName.errors && f.controlName.hasError('minlength') && f.controlName.touched" class="error-msg">
    {{YOUR MESSAGE}}</span>
```

In TS file

```
get f() { return this.form.controls; }
```

Comment: Let me know if you have any issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add  `oninput="this.value = Math.abs(this.value)==0?1: Math.abs(this.value)"` in your input box to avoid the typing of 0 or negative numbers

```
<input matInput type="number" [(ngModel)]="modelName" placeholder="Length"  
min="1" id="Length" name="Length"  oninput="this.value = 
Math.abs(this.value)==0?1: Math.abs(this.value)" required />
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/2VjyBj5coFw5t3sBtF0F?p=preview)

---

OR

try this to manually remove the values in text box after entered wrong values,

```
<input matInput type="number" [(ngModel)]="modelName" placeholder="Length"  min="1" id="Length" name="Length" (change)="valueChange($event)" required>
```

in component

```
valueChange(event) {
    if (event.target.value <= 0) {
     this.modelName = '';
      return false;
    }
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/kum6cI1lWU9fyo60tHAI?p=preview)

Comment: if someone wants to put 0.44 value what it shoud do?

Comment: @MuhammadDaniyal Then try my second demo

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a span element with error styling like red color text which is hidden initially and when the button function is called then check the value of the value exists then show the span if not then keep it hidden

By default it will not throw any error.

It you want to throw an error by default try to use pattern match like this by adding pattern attribute

pattern="^+?[1-9]\d*$". 
In the input.